# Spring ControllerAdvice how to return Json or html page according to Accept request header?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Now, App can return a cutstom 404 page.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handle404(WebRequest request) {
        return "/exceptions/404";
    }

}
```

And I wonder how should I do, if I want to get a JSON when Accept request header is `Accept: application/json`, like this:

````
$> curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/no-such-page

{"timestamp":"2018-04-11T05:56:03.845+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/no-such-page"}```
````

Comment: Crate a class MyClass with LocalDateTime timestamp int status String error, ... and return new ResponseEntity<MyClass>(myClass,HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE). but i am not sure. this question is exactly my question and i am searching for it now.